# Why a fragment is not executing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to call a new fragment in android and when I am clicking the button Search it is working but after to execute the code:

```
Activity ac = (Activity) v.getContext();
AllFragment to = new AllFragment(null, false); 
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = ac.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, to);
fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

after it I see in the emulator the next screen:

[image]

then what I expected is a Listview of Products. The code I have in the fragment it is working perfect.

my fragment code is:

```
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public class AllFragment extends ListFragment {
    String codigo = null;
    boolean esOferta = false;

    public AllFragment(String codigo, boolean esOferta) { 
        this.esOferta = esOferta;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try
        {   
            DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager(inflater.getContext());
            Integer poblacion = null;
            Integer provincia = null;
            String codigo = null;
            ArrayList<ProductsOffers>  data = null;

            if (db.existKey("PROVINCIA")) provincia = new Integer(db.getDatoByKey("PROVINCIA"));
            if (db.existKey("POBLACION")) poblacion = new Integer(db.getDatoByKey("POBLACION"));            
            if (db.existKey("CODIGO")) codigo = db.getDatoByKey("CODIGO");

            if (!this.esOferta) data = IAndroid.getAllProductsAndOffers(provincia, poblacion, this.codigo, null, null);
            else {
                data = IAndroid.getProductsByOfferCode(this.codigo);
            }

            if (data !=  null) setListAdapter(new ProductOffersListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), data));

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {           
        }

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

In my emulator I am using version 4.0.3

My adapter code is:

```
public class ProductOffersListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<info.android.model.ProductsOffers> navProOffers;

    public ProductOffersListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<info.android.model.ProductsOffers> navProOffers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navProOffers = navProOffers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navProOffers.size();     
    }

    @Override
    public info.android.model.ProductsOffers getItem(int position) {        
        return navProOffers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, null);
        }

        ProductsOffers po = (ProductsOffers) getItem(position);


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  TextView vwtipo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vwTipo);
                  TextView vwcodigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);

                  Activity act = (Activity) v.getContext(); 

                  ProductFragment to = new ProductFragment(vwcodigo.getText().toString(), vwtipo.getText().equals("OFERTA"));

                  FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = act.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  fragTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, to);
                  fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                  fragTransaction.commit();
              }

            });

        try
        {       
            ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image); 

            TextView vwtipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vwTipo);
            TextView txtCodigo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            TextView txtCiudad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCiudad);               
            TextView txtVF = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVF);

            String sVF =  Double.toString(getItem(position).ValorFinal) + "€";  

            String aux = "";

            aux = po.tipo;


            vwtipo.setText((aux.equals("O"))? "OFERTA":"PRODUCTO");
            vwtipo.setBackgroundColor(aux.equals("O")?Color.RED: Color.WHITE);

            txtVF.setText(sVF);
            txtCiudad.setText(po.ciudad);
            txtCodigo.setText(po.codigo);

            convertView.setTag(po.codigo);

            img.setImageBitmap(po.Imagen);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Why my fragment is not executing?

Comment: I think your code is fine, it is just your emulator that is a bit slow.

Comment: Which is the best configuration? For the emulator

Comment: Use the Intel x86 emulator. That should speed things up.